# Kannel Configuration fails

Tags: kannel

I am getting below comments when I run ./configure in kannel gateway

config.status: executing libtool commands
sed: can't read ./ltmain.sh: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'libtoolT': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'libtoolT': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access 'libtool': No such file or directory

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

i just resolved this problem by running command libtoolize --force before ./configure on my ubuntu. (on Mac it should be glibtoolize --force)

MAke sure libtools are installed on your system before running the command.Hope this helps